# How to show R plots in vscode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, plot, command-line, data-science

I am new to R, and wanted to get going writing code. I was trying to run my R code with the command line method in the command line:

```
rscript "Hello World.r"
```

The code in *`Hello World.r`* is:

```
library(datasets)
plot(iris)
```

I have `rterm`, `r`, `rgui` and `rscript` all in the PATH variable on my Windows laptop, and I want to use it in VS Code with the command line and without vscode extensions.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to show plots when I run it with `rscript "Hello World.r".

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Try with ``Rscript`` with a capital "R".

Comment: No, doesn't work

Comment: The above message is a reply to @user438383